# Justification/Discussion why std::sort isn't forced to use std::swap

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer

I recently wrote code (relevant [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32026364/1116364), [associated code](http://ideone.com/HhrBGF)) whose swap operation was intended to have different semantics than a combination of copy construction and copy assignment. That's where I recognized that `std::sort` doesn't always use `std::swap` or any `swap` function found through ADL.

For those who aren't familiar with this I put together [a small example](http://ideone.com/OpPHt6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
namespace thing {
struct thing {
 int dummy;
 operator int (void) const {
  return dummy;
 }
 thing (int value) : dummy (value) {}
 thing (thing const & other) : dummy (other.dummy) {
  cout << "copy   " << this << " from " << &other << endl;
 }
 thing & operator=(thing const & other) {
  dummy = other.dummy;
  cout << "assign " << this << " from " << &other << endl;
 }
 void swap (thing & other) {
  // not called
 }
};

void swap (thing & lhs, thing & rhs) {
  // not called
}
}

int main() {
 vector<thing::thing> data  = {1, 21, 42};
 cout << "sorting now" << endl;
 sort (begin (data), end (data), greater<int>{});
 return 0;
}
```

Now the fact *that* `std::sort` isn't always using `std::swap` has been addressed multiple times here on SO:

- [std::sort does not always call std::swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14212701/1116364)
- [Does STL sort use swap or binary copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8219525/1116364)

My **question** is: Has there been any consideration, in terms of a proposal or discussion, to force `std::sort` (and similar standard library functions) to actually use `std::swap`?

To me it feels a bit ... under specified ... that for the correct behavior of my code it's swap operation has to have the same semantics as the combination of copy (move) construction and copy (move) assignment.

I'm well aware of the fact that the actual implementation (using a copy followed by multiple assignments) is far more effective than applying swap to any two elements for sorting.

Comment: This sounds like a question for `std-discussion`, not SO.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. See [issue LWG 226](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#226) and [paper N1523](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1523.htm)

A major issue is exactly what to call. `::std::swap` cannot be overloaded, and unqualified `swap` may not be the right function. In fact, the finance industry has always been a major user of C++, and for them `swap` might very well be a [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_(finance)).